# Inject GitLab CI Variables into Terraform Variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, gitlab, terraform

I'm having a set of Terraform files and in particular one variables.tf file which sort of holds my variables like aws access key, aws access token etc. I want to now automate the resource creation on AWS using GitLab CI / CD.

My plan is the following:

1. Write a .gitlab-ci-yml file
2. Have the terraform calls in the .gitlab-ci.yml file

I know that I can have secret environment variables in GitLab, but I'm not sure how I can push those variables into my Terraform variables.tf file which looks like this now!

```
# AWS Config

variable "aws_access_key" {
  default = "YOUR_ADMIN_ACCESS_KEY"
}

variable "aws_secret_key" {
  default = "YOUR_ADMIN_SECRET_KEY"
}

variable "aws_region" {
  default = "us-west-2"
}
```

In my .gitlab-ci.yml, I have access to the secrets like this:

```
- 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}' 
- 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}' 
- 'AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}'
```

How can I pipe it to my Terraform scripts? Any ideas? I would need to read the secrets from GitLab's environment and pass it on to the Terraform scripts!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure environment variables in Hashicorp Terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55052153/how-to-configure-environment-variables-in-hashicorp-terraform)

Comment: You can just use the SDK's natural way of loading credentials via environment variables using `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Referencing gitlab secrets in Terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52092759/referencing-gitlab-secrets-in-terraform/55564665)

Comment: That port does not answer my question. It requires using another image that has some tool like gettext to be available on the Docker image and I do not want that!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Which executor are you using for your GitLab runners?

You don't necessarily need to use the Docker executor but can use a runner installed on a bare-metal machine or in a VM.

If you install the `gettext` package on the respective machine/VM as well you can use the same method as I described in [Referencing gitlab secrets in Terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52092759/referencing-gitlab-secrets-in-terraform/55564665) for the Docker executor.

Another possibility could be that you set

```
job:
    stage: ...
    variables: 
        TF_VAR_SECRET1: ${GITLAB_SECRET}
```

or

```
job:
    stage: ...
    script:
        - export TF_VAR_SECRET1=${GITLAB_SECRET}
```

in your CI job configuration and interpolate these. Please see [Getting an Environment Variable in Terraform configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629367/getting-an-environment-variable-in-terraform-configuration) as well

Comment: I figured it out from the Terraform documentation that I can prefix ma variables with TF_VAR_, but anyway thanks for posting the solution!

Answer (score 5):

Bear in mind that terraform requires a TF_VAR_ prefix to environment variables. So actually you need something like this in .gitlab-ci.yml

```
- 'TF_VAR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}' 
- 'TF_VAR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}' 
- 'TF_VAR_AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}'
```

Which also means you could just set the variable in the pipeline with that prefix as well and not need this extra mapping step.

I see you actually did discover this per your comment---I'm still posting this answer since I missed your comment the first time and it would have saved me an hour of work.