# How to correct hide secrets in Terraform using GitLab and AWS

Tags: gitlab, terraform, gitlab-ci, secret-key

I want to automate the work of Terraforms using GitLab. I have **working** code that I can run from my local machine and it works without issue. Now I want to transfer it to GitLab. I need to hide my private keys (on the local machine I use environment variables). According to this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56461518/inject-gitlab-ci-variables-into-terraform-variables][1]
I can set environment variables using only the GitLab features. My *gitlab.yml*

```
image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/terraform-images/stable:latest
variables:
  TF_ROOT: ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}
  TF_ADDRESS: ${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/terraform/state/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}

cache:
  key: production
  paths:
    - ${TF_ROOT}/.terraform

before_script:
  - cd ${TF_ROOT}

stages:
  - prepare
  - build
  - deploy

init:
  stage: prepare
  script:
    - gitlab-terraform init

plan:
  stage: build
  variables: 
      aws_access_key: ${TF_AWS_SECRET_KEY}
      aws_secter_key: ${TF_AWS_SECRET_KEY}
      aws_region: ${TF_AWS_REGION}
  script:
    - gitlab-terraform plan
    - gitlab-terraform plan-json
  artifacts:
    name: plan
    paths:
      - ${TF_ROOT}/plan.cache
    reports:
      terraform: ${TF_ROOT}/plan.json

apply:
  stage: deploy
  variables: 
      aws_access_key: ${TF_AWS_SECRET_KEY}
      aws_secter_key: ${TF_AWS_SECRET_KEY}
      aws_region: ${TF_AWS_REGION}
  environment:
    name: production
  script:
    - gitlab-terraform apply
  dependencies:
    - plan
  when: manual
  only:
    - master
```

My *provide.tf*:

```
variable "aws_access_key" {}
variable "aws_secter_key" {}
variable "aws_region" {}

provider "aws" {
    region     = var.aws_region
    access_key = var.aws_access_key
    secret_key = var.aws_secter_key
}
```

My environment variables have created in GitLab->Setting->CI/CD->Variables

TF_AWS_ACCESS_KEY,TF_AWS_REGION, TF_AWS_SECRET_KEY

But when I run my CI/CD pipeline, I take an error, log:

```
    + TF_USERNAME=
    + '[' -z  ]
    + TF_USERNAME=
    + TF_PASSWORD=
    + '[' -n  ]
    + export 'TF_HTTP_ADDRESS=
    + export 'TF_HTTP_LOCK_ADDRESS=
    + export 'TF_HTTP_LOCK_METHOD=POST'
    + export 'TF_HTTP_UNLOCK_ADDRESS=
    + export 'TF_HTTP_UNLOCK_METHOD=DELETE'
    + export 'TF_HTTP_USERNAME=
    + export 'TF_HTTP_PASSWORD=
    + export 'TF_HTTP_RETRY_WAIT_MIN=
    + init
    + terraform_is_at_least 0.13.2
    + head -n1
    + sort -V
    + awk -v 'min=0.13.2' '/^Terraform v/{ sub(/^v/, "", $2); print min; print $2 }'
    + terraform -version
    + '[' 0.13.2 '=' 0.13.2 ]
    + return 0
    + terraform init -reconfigure
    Initializing the backend...
    Successfully configured the backend "http"! Terraform will automatically
    use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.
    Initializing provider plugins...
    - Using previously-installed hashicorp/aws v3.20.0
    - Using previously-installed hashicorp/archive v2.0.0
    The following providers do not have any version constraints in configuration,
    so the latest version was installed.
    To prevent automatic upgrades to new major versions that may contain breaking
    changes, we recommend adding version constraints in a required_providers block
    in your configuration, with the constraint strings suggested below.
    * hashicorp/archive: version = "~> 2.0.0"
    * hashicorp/aws: version = "~> 3.20.0"
    Terraform has been successfully initialized!
    You may now begin working with Terraform. Try running "terraform plan" to see
    any changes that are required for your infrastructure. All Terraform commands
    should now work.
    If you ever set or change modules or backend configuration for Terraform,
    rerun this command to reinitialize your working directory. If you forget, other
    commands will detect it and remind you to do so if necessary.
    + terraform plan '-out=plan.cache'
    var.aws_access_key
      Enter a value: 
    var.aws_region
      Enter a value: 
    var.aws_secter_key
      Enter a value: 
    Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
    The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
    persisted to local or remote state storage.
    data.archive_file.init: Refreshing state...
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Error: Invalid AWS Region: 
    Uploading artifacts for failed job
    00:01
    Uploading artifacts...                     
    Cleaning up file based variables

00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

When I run the same code on the local machine, I haven't got any problems. I think that environment variables are not substituted in the provide.tf. How can I properly organize the hiding of my private keys and how can I run the code on GitLab?
A small sub-question, I did not figure out how to store the .tfstate file remotely on the app.terraform.io servers, is there any manual for beginners?
[1]: [Inject GitLab CI Variables into Terraform Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56461518/inject-gitlab-ci-variables-into-terraform-variables)

Comment: Hi @Dmitry, how do you populate the TF variables such as `var.aws_region` on your local? By a .tfvars file?

Comment: No, I exports 3 variables, and Terraform correctly paste they. And I do export only once. @adp